# ASP.NET use AJAX to prevent a control from reloading

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm using VS2008 to develop my ASP.NET web site, I know how to use AJAX and update panels to perform partial page refresh, but is there any way that I can do the reverse action? i.e. can I use update panels to prevent some controls from reloads? I have a control which I don't want to be reloaded in page reloads, it is located in my master page as it should be active in all pages, what are my options now?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using UpdateMode property of update panel to Conditional..

When UpdateMode set to Conditional, the UpdatePanel will be updated only on postback originated by controls inside the panel or from the triggers specified.

for more info:

http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/05/24/updatemode-default-value-for-the-updatepanel-is-always.aspx

http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

Regards.